# What does the return value of Cipher.dofinal(byte[]) mean in Java?

Tags: java, encryption

I have a `Cipher aesEncryptCipher` in encrypt mode using AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding.

Why do the following two functions return two different things? What does the return value of `encrypt2` mean? According to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#doFinal%28%29), it's supposed to return "the new buffer with the result", which I assumed to mean "the encrypted bytes".

```
public byte[] encrypt(byte[] rawBytes) {
   aesEncryptCipher.doFinal(rawBytes);
   return rawBytes;
}

public byte[] encrypt2(byte[] rawBytes) {
   return aesEncryptCipher.doFinal(rawBytes);
}
```

Using some init vector and key,

```
encrypt("xxx".getBytes("UTF-8"));
returns [120, 120, 120]

encrypt2("xxx".getBytes("UTF-8"));
returns [-76, 22, 46, 63, -16, -29, 56, -85, -115, -77, 11, 16, -56, 95, 20, 29]
```

Comment: Well, what's the return value of `Cipher.doFinal(byte[] bytes)`? From a glance at it, it looks like the method does not modify the `byte[]` in-place (which is to be expected), so your first method would return the input while the second would (presumably) return the encrypted result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one returns the original, unencrypted bytes (the input), and the second one returns the result of the encryption (the output).

Comment: I just figured that out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `encrypt` function returns the plain text, while `encrypt2` returns the encrypted data.

This is because `doFinal` only looks at the byte array it gets, it does not modify it.